# Plone e-mail silently fails

Tags: email, centos5, email-server, silent, plone

I'm new to Linux and Plone.  I installed Plone 4.0.2 on CentOS 5.5 and while everything else seems to work well enough (I got repozo working for backups today, for instance) Plone doesn't seem to be able to e-mail anyone to reset their passwords.  I have the same e-mail settings in `Site Setup -> Mail` as other scripts that work fine on our network.  I have two users created while logged in as admin and with their e-mail addresses input correctly, but neither the "forgot your password" link on the login screen nor going to `Site Setup -> Users and Groups`, clicking Reset Password checkboxes, and clicking Apply Changes results in an e-mail coming to either user.  Both of us have meanwhile been receiving e-mail normally, including from the same address set up as the 'from' address in Plone, but sent by other scripts.

`Site Setup -> Errors` shows nothing.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went and asked on the Plone lists.  Turns out Plone will complain loudly if it can't get the message to the SMTP server, so I had to check the logs there and correct an SSL setting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do the following:

- Restart Plone in foreground mode: `bin/instance fg`
- Use the feedback form to send email to the admin. (http://plonesite/contact-info)
- Reset one password to make plone send email.
- Go back to the console and see if Plone has puked some error.
- If plone does not complain, then the emails are probable getting stuck somewhere else,outside Plone.